# how to fix usage of pyspark.dbutils on databricks which was used in development by databricks connect?

Tags: databricks

we have developed the code using databricks connect and used *from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils*, while packaging the code to databricks in a wheel file, it fails with an error no module found pyspark.dbutils.

There is no pip install pyspark.dbutils present.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Dbutils should already be available with databricks-connect, so import it using this script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import dbutils
import argparse

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() 

setting = spark.conf.get("spark.master")
if "local" in setting:
    from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
    dbutils = DBUtils(spark.sparkContext)
else:
    print("Do nothing - dbutils should be available already")
```